# Search not working on AAM URL

Tags: 2013, search, alternate-access-mapping

I have configured AAM in SP13 Environment.  Now When I am using site via default URL (servername:80), search is working fine.

But when I am searching in the same site via AAM URL it is showing the following error:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: You could find some work arrounds with different scenario over http://sathiya.io/sharepoint/sharepoint-crawling-not-working-with-non-default-zone-public-facing-site.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your Internet URL to Alternate access mapping.

The problem is due to the dedicated services farm not being aware of the AAM settings on the farm that is crawled. Fortunately, SharePoint has provided an easy solution for giving the crawling farm a hint about this, via `External Resource Mapping`.

This below given link will give you a proper solution with step by step instructions to follow.

[Beware crawling the non-Default zone for a SharePoint 2013 Web Application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/02/20/beware-crawling-the-non-default-zone-for-a-sharepoint-2013-web-application/)

You can find the easy steps from this link as well.

[Contextual search not working with alternate accessing mapping](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thomsven/2012/05/10/contextual-search-not-working-with-alternate-accessing-mapping/)